# PHP queries inside loop

Tags: php, sql, performance

### How many queries are ok to be run against your database.

- I am running simple sql queries inside for loop. Estimated no of queires which are running inside loop is 2000.
- Does it affect my performance. If it does then up to which extend.

### Table A

> ```
> code     name
> 1        abc
> 2        xyz
> 4        lol
> 6        lll
> ```
>
> ### Table B

```
code      year    no
1         1990    406
6         2016    510
2         2017    777
6         2017    511
2         2016    777
```

I want to display data in a table like:

```
Name  1990  1991  1992  .............2017
abc    1      0     0                  0
xyz    0      0     0                  1
```

Comment: Sorry, this is way too broad.

Comment: Depends upon your queries. Simple select queries have relatively no overhead. Update, delete, replace have a lot of overheads. Complex select queries will depend on what is indexed and the structure of the query itself. Having 2000 queries within a loop tells me that you haven't got a good database design.

Comment: Agree with @jeff the loop sounds suspicious.  Typically it is the job of the database to worry about iterating a table, not the PHP code.

Comment: You should paste your code here so that we can suggest you how to optimize it.

Comment: i have edited my question please check

Comment: You must execute least query to database for better performance..

Comment: Show here the code /Loop you are using

Comment: yes, i am using select statement for each year and code